# Nextjs child pages call layout parent function

Tags: reactjs, next.js

In `nextJS` I have a `layout.js` which has a function `parentLayoutFn()` and renders `children` pages.

I want to call `parentLayoutFn` from all the children pages.

**ParentLayout: /layouts**

```js
export default function ParentLayout() {
  function parentLayoutFn() { 
    // router.push(...), other logic, ...
  }
  return ({children})
}
```

**Child Page A: /layouts/pageA**

```js
export default function ChildPageA() {
  return(
    <SomeComponent onCustomCallback={parentLayoutFn}></SomeComponent>
  )
}
```

**Child Page B: /layouts/pageB**

```js
export default function ChildPageB() {
  
  function someEvent() {
     parentLayoutFn();
  }

  return(
    <button onClick={someEvent}></button>
  )
}
```

I have looked at createContext and Provider, but I don't understand how to use them or let's say that didn't work.

In Vue I could pass it as a `props` or simply `emit` an Event to the parent. How can this be achieve in React / NextJS?

Thank you!